# Assign ContextMenu Item Click event in a resourceDictionary.xaml file

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary

I want to know if I could assign item click event to this context menu that it is placed in an .Xaml file of type `ResourceDictionary` which one does not have code behind class, however i know that i can manually assign a .cs class to this .xaml.

But I dont want to assign a file class to it because I already have another .Xaml file with its own .cs file class in which i would want to register the itemClick event.

My code in the resourcedictionary file is:

```html
<ContextMenu>
<MenuItem Header="Show SoundRecorder" Click="ItemClick"></MenuItem>
<Separator/>
<MenuItem Header="Start Recording Now"></MenuItem>
<MenuItem Header="Stop Recording"></MenuItem>
<Separator/> 
<MenuItem Header="About"></MenuItem>
<MenuItem Header="Exit SoundRecorder"></MenuItem>
</ContextMenu>
```

**How could i achieve this approach?**

Answer (score 1):

Create a command in a data context for the view with the context menu.

```
public ICommand ItemClickCommand{ get; set; }
```

Then, you can bind the MenuItem's Command property to the new command.

```
<ContextMenu>
<MenuItem Header="Show SoundRecorder" Command="{Binding ItemClickCommand}"></MenuItem>
<Separator/>
<MenuItem Header="Start Recording Now"></MenuItem>
<MenuItem Header="Stop Recording"></MenuItem>
<Separator/> 
<MenuItem Header="About"></MenuItem>
<MenuItem Header="Exit SoundRecorder"></MenuItem>
</ContextMenu>
```

At runtime, if WPF finds the command in the data context it will bind the menu item to it. Otherwise, it will issue a warning in the Output console.

I will not go here on implementing the `ICommand` interface. There are plenty of googlable implementations.